# Not able to Create New App in iTunes Connect with App Manager Role

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Right now I am not able to create new app from [iTunes connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) portal. Even though I got `App Manager` role and have got access to certificates & profiles. Weird Behaviour - After selecting `+ New App`, it will redirects to landing page.

[image: Create app screenshot from itunes connect portal of Apple.]

Is this iTunes connect bug ? or else what could be the reason?

Comment: have you create certificate of your app and all ?

Comment: Develop certificate created.

Comment: app id and provision profile all created ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Agent` gave me the role `Manager`, However, he missed to give access to -

> Certificates, Identifiers & Profile

In Users & Access -> Developer Roles section check box. 
[image: user access check box image]